# How do I turn off auto-accent in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

When I type in double e's like "teeth", the double e's are automatically replaced with ê. It's quite annoying as I can't type some double letters. How do I turn this off?

Comment: Are you using a localized version of Windows? If so, which?

Comment: Your d's seem to be off aswell.

Answer (score 5):

In your Regional Settings, instead of an English | US keyboard, you have selected English | United States (International). Possibly, your default system language has also been changed from "US" to "United States / Intl"

Just change it back to US and it should be fine.

Comment: I didt had ê's, but instead apostrophe and tilde keys made a "flying accent" behaviour (e.g. apostrophe then a produced an á). Switching from US Intl to simple US fixed it.

Comment: Same problem on Windows 10. Described fix also works here.

Answer (score 3):

Pressing ctrl-shift (using the left shift key) will toggle accents for some keyboard configurations.

Answer (score 1):

If you need multi language support, it would be better to turn on Language Bar so you could switch input language on the fly on any program. If language bar is on your desktop already, you might want to try to switch it to EN to type in English without the auto corrections.

If you did not had language bar or just wanted to remove your non-English input support. Go to the "Region and Language" option in control panel, click on "Change keyboards and input methods". Then click the change keyboards button and from here you could add or remove the keyboards you want, then go to the Language Bar tab to configure where you want to show the language bar.

Comment: Also, check if you're using something like US international keyboard or similar.

Answer (score 0):

It looks similar to using the [Telex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telex_(IME)) input method, which is a convention for writing Vietnamese.  [How to type in vietnamese language using unikey ? please help?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091116092745AABpWDO) is what pointed me in this direction, but I don't know see that is a built in option of Windows 7.  I found [Adding Asian IMEs (Chinese and Japanese) for Windows 7](http://www.wfu.edu/~yipcw/atg/ime/w7/) for Chinese or Japanese IMEs, but no mention of Vietnamese in that article.  Follow the steps in that article and see if your keyboard is set to something other that English US.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked all around MS's official help and knowledge bases and it doesn't seem like this is anything that Windows has built in.

The double typing of the same letter to make the accented letter leads me to believe that it's some sort of third party software.  It looks a lot like [VPSKeys](http://www.vps.org/article.php3?id_article=274).

Check in your "Programs and Features" in Control Panel to make sure there's nothing there that you don't recognize.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an AutoCorrect setting if you're using Microsoft Word or similar.

To check this, go into the relevant settings in Word; in Word 2007 you get to this by clicking the big menu button, selecting Word Options, then Proofing, then AutoCorrect options.

Have a look in there to see if someone has set ee to AutoCorrect to ê.